# Magento2 Order status is getting changed even after sales_order_creditmemo_save_after

Tags: magento2, status

Magento2 I am facing issue where my order status is getting changed to Pending even after I set the order status in this event

sales_order_creditmemo_save_after

How should I solve this? Any idea.

Comment: hello dear, can you tell me what exact step you applied on the back side? what do you want?